# let user select an image from the drawable folder

Tags: android, gallery

I want to select image from my android studio drawable folder, which now I have 2 images in it named example.jpg and sue.PNG.
and I define an array as

```
int image[] = {R.drawable.example, R.drawable.sue};
```

how should I further open them as a gallery and let user to pick one from? (as shown below in the second image)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Open a new Activity with `GridView` inside it , and inflate the list of images you have from drawable.  Use `registerForActivityResult` to handle the callback of selected image from user

Comment: can you help provide a example? " inflate the list of images you have from drawable"

Comment: I have explained the process and provided the links on your second question, you can check that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69536760/issue-when-opening-drawable-gallery-to-choose-image-from/69536931#69536931

Answer (score 0):

Try this . On your button click

open Intent

```
public void imageChooser() {
    // Gallery Intent
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent , "Select Picture"), 200);
}
```

Handle the image result

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 200) {
            // Get the uri 
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            if (null != selectedImageUri) {
                // update your imageview 
                yourimageview.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no image to choose from when I enter the gallery, you know why?

Comment: Please explain where you are facing issue. The above code will help you to choose the images and show in your imageview.

Comment: sry, Actually it opens the gallery, but this gallery is not drawable only, it is a 'Recent' gallery, which also includes other images on the device, how should I fix it?   by the way after I choose the new image, the original image still presents

Comment: Ok. Create an activity and put a grid view in the xml. Draw all the images from raw folder in this activity . Here you have only the images which are in raw folder and user can select the images.